# Listing all unimplemented methods called from within a method

Tags: java, recursion, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, javassist

We have a huge project where many methods have been declared upfront and implementations are in progress. All declared methods have a body which simply throws an exception, say, UnimplException.
Now since the methods have been declared and a valid (compilable) body has been provided, they can be called from within other methods.

Now the question is that is there any way to list all such unimplemented (having just a compilable body throwing a particular exception) methods given a particular method?

To illustrate more(the code is to convey the idea and not strictly compiler friendly):

```
class A {
    methA () {
        throw new UnimplException();
    }
}

class B {
    methB () {
        // proper body
        // and calls methA
        A.methA();
        // does something else
        // and returns.
    }
}

class C {
    methC () {
        // proper body
        // calls methB
        B.methB();
    }
}
```

So, if we start from, say, methC, then we want to travel all the way down the method tree to reach to methA because methC calls methB (which is properly implemented and we are not interested) which in turn calls methA which is not properly implemented and that is what we want to find.
We want to search for all such unimplemented methods starting from a method and going few levels deep until we cover all such unimplemented methods.

We thought of JavaAssist but we aren't sure how to go down all the levels because it seems to be giving us all methods called from within a method but not recursively.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is using grep an option?

Comment: This won't even compile. You can't have `throws` in the body, it would have to be `throw new UnimplException()`, and put `throws UnimplException` right after `methA()`. `methA()` and `methB()` are also not static so you can't call them like that.

Comment: From the code you've posted, trying to compile would make the java compiler flag every unimplemented method, because they are throwing an exception without reporting it (or even throwing it properly; you need the new keyword and `UnimplException()`)

Comment: @Fildor It sounds like the OP asks for the unimplemented leafs of a call tree rooting from a certain method, not just a list of all methods having a throw statement in them.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse you can click on the Exception `UnimplException` and `Ctrl+Shift+G` to show all references to the class in your workspace. Alternatively you can right-click on the Exception and `References -> Workspace`

Comment: The code is just a sample..and throws was a typo; it should have been throw...but the sample is mostly to convey the idea...the actual code conpiles fine.

Comment: @Flown the eclipse option will probably show me all methods in the project which throws that exception and not the ones which are in a particular call tree starting from a given method...

Comment: @popeye I think there is no tool that will provide you that information

Comment: Your pseudo code isn’t touching the relevant issues here. If these methods are all supposed to be `static`, you may construct such a call graph without ambiguity. But real-life projects tend to have subclasses and use Polymorphism, so a single invocation may have lot’s of potential targets. Trying to build an entire graph with multiple late binding invocations will soon end in an exploding number of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this project: https://github.com/gousiosg/java-callgraph? This appears to do the Java introspection part, listing every method call from every method in a jar file. I'd try using that to do the heavy lifting of parsing your code, then just recurse through the results.

Something like:

1. Use the callgraph code to build a list of all method calls.
2. Save that data somewhere.
3. Recursively parse that structure to find matching methods.

So from your example, step 1 would give something like the following:

```
A:methA -> UnimplException:<init>
B:methB -> A:methA
C:methC -> B:methB
```

Then shove those in a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and do a fairly straightforward recursive search:

```
// this is populated from the output of the callgraph code
com.google.common.collect.Multimap<String, String> methodMap;

void checkAllMethods() {
  for (String method : methodMap.keySet()) {
    List<String> callStack = new ArrayList<>();
    if (doesMethodThrowUnimplException(method, callStack)) {
      System.out.println(method);
      // can print callStack too if interested
    }
  }
}  

boolean doesMethodThrowUnimplException(String method, List<String> callStack) {
  for (String child : methodMap.get(method)) {
    // have to check the exact method name from callgraph
    if (child.equals("UnimplException:<init>")) {
      return true;
    }
    // recurse into child if not already seen
    if (!callStack.contains(child)) {
      callStack.add(child);
      if (doesMethodThrowUnimplException(child, callStack)) {
        return true;
      }
      callStack.remove(callStack.size() - 1);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Doesn't strictly satisfy your requirements as this will report any method which throws the `UnimplException`, not those who only throw the exception, but not sure if that matters.

Standard disclaimer - just typed this in - haven't compiled / run it, so may well be typos, but hopefully the idea helps.

Comment: thanks @Barney! 
I'll try this out...the idea sounds good. :)

Comment: @popeye no worries - hope it helps. Just tried the codegraph stuff and a quick look seems to work pretty well. Also just updated the recursive code - previous version would fail if a code loop was detected before a call to an exception method.